# Bash hangs evaluating extended globing

Tags: bash

I have the following example script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

app.exit () { 
    printf "I am exiting\n"
    builtin exit
}

app.abort () {
    printf "\nI am aborting\n"
    exit
}

trap app.abort SIGHUP SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGTERM
trap app.exit EXIT

output="This is a test 1  run() : core 2  assert() : core"

test="This+( )is+( )a+( )test*(*)+([0-9])+( )assert()+( ):+( )core*(*)+( )"

shopt -s extglob

set -x
[[ "$output" == $test ]] && echo "match" || echo "not match"
set +x

exit 0
```

This has a couple issues that has me scratching my head.

As you can see, I am using extended globing to evaluate two strings. String `output` is the output from an application. String `test` is the expected value using extended globing.

I expect this to print "not match" since the test string contains a trailing `+( )` (one or more spaces) and the output string does not contain a trailing space.

However, when this is evaluated, bash simply hangs which brings me to the next issue.

As you can see I have trapped the interrupts and exit to allow a graceful termination (removing any temporary files, and such). When the script hangs during the evaluation, I can no longer control-c out.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

I do know how to fix the test string so it no longer fails the evaluation. My biggest concern is that the test string is one of many from a configuration file that gets evaluated at another location in my application. If it hangs, everything stops.

Does anyone have any idea what is happening here? The fact that this just hangs and cannot be terminated, seems like s serious issue with bash.

Comment: What are `a` and `b`?  Do you mean these to be `output` and `test`?

Comment: Looks like `*(*)` is a bug. Try changing it to `?(*)`. You might want to file a bug report  (see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Comment: Isn't `*(*)` the same as `*` in terms of what they'll match?

Comment: Seems to be falling into some infinite loop though.

Comment: Note that your pattern won't match: there is stuff between the digits and "assert" that is not spaces.

Comment: For further reading: https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html -- but note I don't know how extended patterns are implemented.

Comment: As warned in the above article: beware of patterns given to you by strangers. Your script might want to reject patterns that contain `*(*)`

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, I corrected this typo

Comment: @glennjackman that does prevent it from hanging. I will likely file a bug report.

Comment: @glennjackman I did add a check for *(*) to my check. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off of the comments on the question, and using this minimal example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

aaa="This is a test 1  run() : core 2  assert() : core"
bbb="_(*)a"

shopt -s extglob

[[ "$aaa" == $bbb ]] && echo "match" || echo "not match"
```

The same behavior (very long / infinite runtime) occurs if the `_` is *either* a `+` or a `*` *and* there is something after it, i.e., where the `a` in `$bbb` is.

If `$bbb` is just `+(*)` or `*(*)`, then it exits quickly (with a 'match').  Going further, if `$bbb` *ends in* `+(*)` or `*(*)`, then it exits quickly.  The key seems to be having something after `+(*)` or `*(*)`.

On the whole, and without having a way to directly validate this, I agree with some earlier comments that seem to have been deleted, that this "smells like" exponential or infinite backtracking.

I also agree with @chepner that `*` would always mean the same thing as either `+(*)` or `*(*)`, and makes a perfect (and to me, preferable) substitute while you await a bugfix.

Comment: I have actually added a check for occurrence in the globing string of (*)